# How do I create a physical folder in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, directory

Is it possible to create an actual physical folder via Visual Studio 2012?

When right-clicking on the Solution only gives me the option to create a Solution Folder, which are really "virtual folders".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to create a project in that solution. Then you can add as many folders as you like.

A solution is a way to group a set of projects that can / need to be built together etc.

Comment: When creating a project, I can only create Visual ** projects. I can't find a "blank project". What options do I have? https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8183146/persistent/stackoverflow/Image6.png

Comment: A visual project is VB.NET. You need to add a new project for whatever language you are planning on using whether it's C# or VB.